# Как в golang использовать c или c++ код?

Tags: c++, c, golang

Подскажите простой пример использования функции из c \ c++ в программе на golang.
Например на c \ c++  будет функция sayHello возвращающая значение -

> "Привет,Роман, это значение из функции"

.
Вот этот текст я хочу получить в программе на golang.
Как это сделать? я читал-ещё нужно установить компилятор gcc .
Можете пожалуйста привести примеры.
Спасибо

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Объявите класс

```
// foo.hpp
class cxxFoo {
public:
  int a;
  cxxFoo(int _a):a(_a){};
  ~cxxFoo(){};
  void Bar();
};

// foo.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.hpp"
void
cxxFoo::Bar(void){
  std::cout<<this->a<<std::endl;
}
```

интерфейс С

```
// foo.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  typedef void* Foo;
  Foo FooInit(void);
  void FooFree(Foo);
  void FooBar(Foo);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Реализация

```
//cfoo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
#include "foo.h"
Foo FooInit()
{
  cxxFoo * ret = new cxxFoo(1);
  return (void*)ret;
}
void FooFree(Foo f)
{
  cxxFoo * foo = (cxxFoo*)f;
  delete foo;
}
void FooBar(Foo f)
{
  cxxFoo * foo = (cxxFoo*)f;
  foo->Bar();
}
```

Go file

```
package foo
// #include "foo.h"
import "C"
import "unsafe"
type GoFoo struct {
     foo C.Foo;
}
func New()(GoFoo){
     var ret GoFoo;
     ret.foo = C.FooInit();
     return ret;
}
func (f GoFoo)Free(){
     C.FooFree(unsafe.Pointer(f.foo));
}
func (f GoFoo)Bar(){
     C.FooBar(unsafe.Pointer(f.foo));
}
```

Makefile

```
// makefile
TARG=foo
CGOFILES=foo.go
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.$(GOARCH)
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.pkg
foo.o:foo.cpp
    g++ $(_CGO_CFLAGS_$(GOARCH)) -fPIC -O2 -o $@ -c $(CGO_CFLAGS) $<
cfoo.o:cfoo.cpp
    g++ $(_CGO_CFLAGS_$(GOARCH)) -fPIC -O2 -o $@ -c $(CGO_CFLAGS) $<
CGO_LDFLAGS+=-lstdc++
$(elem)_foo.so: foo.cgo4.o foo.o cfoo.o
    gcc $(_CGO_CFLAGS_$(GOARCH)) $(_CGO_LDFLAGS_$(GOOS)) -o $@ $^ $(CGO_LDFLAGS)
```

Тестирование

```
// foo_test.go
package foo
import "testing"
func TestFoo(t *testing.T){
    foo := New();
    foo.Bar();
    foo.Free();
}
```

Установка библиотеки

```
gotest
rm -f _test/foo.a _gotest_.6
6g -o _gotest_.6 foo.cgo1.go foo.cgo2.go foo_test.go
rm -f _test/foo.a
gopack grc _test/foo.a _gotest_.6  foo.cgo3.6
1
PASS
```