# Вызов собственной функции на C из программы на GO

Tags: c, golang

Как вызвать собственную C-функцию из программы на Go?

И если можно приведите пример.

Comment: посмотрите у меня в вопросах было

Comment: @RakzinRoman, так поиска по вопросам вроде бы нету, может сами приведете ссылку?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два основных способа - [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) и [SWIG](https://golang.org/misc/swig/stdio/). С помощью cgo например (main.c):

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
void f(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

И main.go:

```
// main.go
package main

// #include "main.c"
import "C"

func main() {
    C.f()
}
```

Кладёте оба в одну папку, вызываете `go build` и готово.

Comment: То что надо вроде бы) Благодарю)

Answer (score 0):

[Как в golang использовать c или c++ код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548017/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-golang-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-c-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-c-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)

https://www.goinggo.net/2013/08/using-c-dynamic-libraries-in-go-programs.html

Comment: А без такой возни по другому не как?

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.